# My discord bot doesn't seem to be executing a function on member join

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm new to coding discord bots, so this might be some easy fix mistake I made but when a member joins my server, the bot doesn't seem to react, be it to add a role or just send a random message in the console.
I'd also add, I'm using replit to host my bot.

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from replit import db

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("I'm in")
  print(client.user)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  if message.content == "ping":
    await message.channel.send("pong")

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print("A member has joined")
    role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, id="920344130184437931")
    await client.add_roles(member, role)
```

Comment: Is this your full code? Your bot is missing `client.run()` call, and it also doesn't have a token.

Comment: Whoops, forgot to add that last part. It does have a client.run() call and token. Aside from that that's all that I forgot to add which might affect anything. I'll add that it replies without problem to the on_message function. It's just on_member_join

Comment: You should make sure that the `discord.Channel` is visible to the bot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable **Privileged Gateway Intents** in [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications).
When you enable that, you need to type this in your code:

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot('PREFIX',intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("I'm in")
    ....
```

After that **on_member_join** event should work

[image]

Comment: I should have tought it before: `discord.Intents` is always causing errors among beginners. +1